# How to track down terrible performance at a specific time of day?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5

I have an ASP.NET MVC-4, Entity Framework 5 application running on IIS7, with a SQL Server 2012 database.

Every day, between 7:45 and 8:15, several hundred users perform the same routine daily tasks. And performance is *terrible*. We're getting timeouts all over the place.

So today I sat watching with several diagnostic tools. On SQL Server Profiler, I saw hundreds of queries timing out after 30 seconds. I copied the query and put it into SQL Sentry to see what was happening in the query plan. 30 minutes later the query finally executed, showing a completely asinine, inefficient execution plan. Index scans returning tens of millions of records, which should have been filtered down to tens, maybe hundreds of records by an earlier join.

Meanwhile, I was checking on Performance Monitor for other diagnostics. CPU was cruising at a comfortable 20-30%, we have 256 GB of RAM of which about 200 are reserved for SQL Server, and no shortage of working memory. No significant db locking, no deadlocks. Just horrible, horrible performance.

So later I tried running the *exact same* query. It came back in about 0.1 seconds. And the query plan looked totally different: everything was index seeks, nice thin lines and everything. Every other query that I had captured in SQL Profiler that had taken over 5 seconds between 7:45-8:15 was now returning in sub-0.1 second time.

We have the same problem every day, during the same time window. How do I go about troubleshooting this? I think there may be some clue from the different query plans when the queries are executed at different times; could this be something to do with SQL statistics? If so, how do we resolve it?

**EDIT:** I took @t_m's advice and deployed a DMV script.  Now I can see for sure what execution plan was followed when the query timed out, versus what plan it follows when it works.

- [**Good** query plan here](http://biz.jjcf.info/stackoverflow/goodqueryplan.xml)
- [**Bad** query plan here](http://biz.jjcf.info/stackoverflow/badqueryplan.xml)
- [**Ugly** query itself here](http://biz.jjcf.info/stackoverflow/query.txt)

Comment: Is it timeouts due to performance or locks? I suspect the latter if CPU isn't spiking.

Comment: (or you could schedule regular maintenance every day from 7:45 to 8:15! :P)

Comment: can you show what one ore 2 of the query's look like..? are you doing any Locking ? are there any Triggers being performed..? what about Indexing..? this can actually be a number of things..? it's really hard to answer a question of this nature without seeing any type of coding

Comment: Yup, looks like concurrency issues in the SQL query, perhaps each trying to lock the rows in order to ensure no stale data comes back

Comment: Sounds like you have a bad cached plan in the SQL Server plan cache. This can be caused by the first query having unusual parameters.

Comment: Might want to checkout [monitoring script with DMV](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1861/sql-server-monitoring-scripts-with-the-dmvs/), If it's a blocking issue, there is a column called `blocking_session_id` in one of the DMV's.

Comment: @DavidG, there was (almost) no locking.  I checked `select * from master..sysprocesses where blocked>0` while the queries were timing out, and consistently got nothing back.

Comment: @DJKRAZE The queries are ugly, really ugly - generated by Entity Framework from Linq.  No triggers.  Now that I've seen the discrepancy between the query plans, I'll make a point of snagging the XML of the two different plans tomorrow during the "bad" time and the "good" time, and I'll post, if I haven't found a solution by then.

Comment: @samy, as I commented before, there was no locking showing up in master..sysprocesses

Comment: @t_m thanks for that tip, might be useful...

Comment: @SteveFord, a bad cached plan, every day at the same time?  That may be - but how to solve it?  With what diagnostic tools?  Looking at what metrics?

Comment: @DJKRAZE updated question with the good, the bad and the ugly

Comment: @SteveFord courtesy ping, please see updated question

Comment: @t_m courtesy ping, please see updated question.  Thanks for the CMV tip, it came in handy!

Comment: @DavidG by the way, there was very little locking in the DMV table, but what little there was, was all caused by this query.

Comment: @ShaulBehr Yeah, ugly is the word! The slow plan seems to be trying to sort 400k rows. I'd be surprised if the Linq couldn't be rewritten/improved in some way.

Comment: @DavidG, that's what I'm currently working on.

Comment: @ShaulBehr .. Download `SQL Sentry Plan Explorer` .. there is a free version and is very useful to get additional information from your plans. From `SQL Sentry Plan Explorer`, the bottleneck is `Sort` by 16 columns .. Estimated Rows: 386,511, Estimated Row Size: 23,723 B and Estimated Data Size: 8,744 MB. As you can see you are retrieving 8.7 GB of data and sorting by 16 columns might slow it down a bit. Estimated I/O Cost between Good plan `0.001500` compare to Bad plan `544.0752`. BTW.. Looks like the SQL query is different in the plans you posted between Good/Bad plan.

Comment: @t_m Thanks, been using SQL Sentry for about a year now, love it!  Very odd that the queries could be different.  Anyway I'm refactoring all the code now...

Comment: Total guess, is there any DB maintenance going on at that time? Maybe somebody set up a scheduled job that drops and recreates one of the indexes at that time of day, or something along those lines?

Comment: @ShaulBehr your link to goodqueryplan doesn't work.